# How can I get my bump map less extreme?

Tags: materials, shaders, shader-nodes, bump

So I am mixing a bump map and normal map. I can turn the strength down which gives the effect I want for the bump map, but that decreases the strength of my normal map which I do NOT want. I tried using a color ramp to decrease it but it made it look terrible. This is what I have, it's way too strong.
[image]

When I try to mess with the color ramp to change how intense the effect is, i get these weird separated bumps, it doesnt matter what i do (lightening the black does the exact same thing).
[image]

This is a render of what happens when I mess with the color ramp. This is NOT what i want, i was an even spread amount of bumps like the top just not as strong.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the "add vector" node, adding both the bump and normal vectors seperatley?

Comment: instead of strength, maybe modifying the distance value of the bump map?

Comment: I am not very advanced so I don't even know what the add vector node is, nor how to add them separately. I am going to try to look into that!

Comment: Marty, thank you so much! This has given me the effect I was looking for. Using distance value worked pretty well! Appreciate it

Comment: also what does it give if you change the ColorRamp value? Try to whiten the black or darken the white

Comment: I did, I showed an example of what happens when I do that and its the last photo. I tried both darkening and lightening both, and get this horrible result. Thankfully, changing the distance value worked just fine

Comment: it doesn't look like you've darkened or lightened (in your pictures at least), it looks more like you've moved the needles

Comment: i just didnt screenshot that part but i messed w the values for like 15 minutes